# In Magento2, I want to add cms page link in header top menu before wishlist link

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I want to add custom **cms page link** in header menu before **wishlist** link.

Please tell me how we can add custom page link before wishlist link?

Comment: Which is theme are you use in ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add bellow code to in your theme default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="cms-page-name"  before="wish-list-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">cms-page-name</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">cms-page-path</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Clean cache and check.

Let me know if you have any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just override template file for wishlist into your theme.

path,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/Magento_Wishlist/templates/link.phtml
```

Now you can write down your cms page link code before wishlist code,
     
this tag.

```
<?php $link = 'Cms page link'; ?>
    <div class="link cmspage">
        <a <?php echo $link; ?>>CMS Page</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Links\Link" name="linkname" before='wish-list-link'/>
                </block>
     </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Links\Link.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Links;
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getHref(){

    $page_url = '[cms url key]'; 
    return $this->getUrl($page_url);
}

public function getLabel(){
     return '[Link Name]';
}
}
```